# Extract an MLPRegressor attributes (n_iter_ ) for the best model in a pipeline with GridsearchCV?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, gridsearchcv, mlp

I made a `GridsearchCV` with a pipeline and I want to extract one attribute (`n_iter_`) of a component of the pipeline (MLPRegressor) for the best model.

I'm using Python 3.0.

**Creation of the pipeline**

```
pipeline_steps = [('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('MLPR', MLPRegressor(solver='lbfgs', early_stopping=True, validation_fraction=0.1, max_iter=10000))]

MLPR_parameters = {'MLPR__hidden_layer_sizes':[(50,), (100,), (50,50)], 'MLPR__alpha':[0.001, 10, 1000]}

MLPR_pipeline = Pipeline(pipeline_steps)

gridCV_MLPR = GridSearchCV(MLPR_pipeline, MLPR_parameters, cv=kfold)
gridCV_MLPR.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

When I want to extract the best model with `gridCV_GBR.best_params_`, I only have the result for the GridsearchCV :

```
{'MLPR__alpha': 0.001, 'MLPR__hidden_layer_sizes': (50,)}
```

But I want to have the number of iteration of MLPRegressor used by the best model of `gridCV_MLPR`.

How is it possible to use the `n_iter_` attribute designed for `MLPRegressor()` through the pipeline with GridsearhCV ?

Comment: What about `gridCV_MLPR.best_estimator_.n_iter_`?

Comment: With this code, I have **'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'n_iter_'**. It's normal because **.n_iter_** is an attribute of MLPregressor(). Which is included in a pipeline (the best one, defined by the GridsearchCV).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your help,

I found the solution :

```
gridCV_MLPR.best_estimator_.named_steps['MLPR'].n_iter_
```

As the `gridCV_MLPR.best_estimator_` is a pipeline, we need to select the MLPRegressor parameters with `.named_steps['MLPR']`.

Thanks a lot for your very, very quick answer ...

Comment: Good job (+1); after the 2 days period, don't forget to actually [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).